# laravel 5.3 session accessing for shopping cart

Tags: php, session, laravel-5, session-variables

Every time i press add to cart button the old cart replaces the new one rather than adding the new item to old cart and it doesnt update the quantity if it is present.Following are the codes and the images.

my Cart.php Model

```
class Cart{

public $spares=null;
public $totalQuantity=0;
public $totalPrice=0;

public function __construct($oldCart){
    if($oldCart){
        $this->spares=$oldCart->spares;
        $this->totalPrice=$oldCart->totalQuantity;
        $this->totalQuantity=$oldCart->totalQuantity;
    }
    else{
        $this->spares=null;
    }

}

public function add($spare,$id){
     $storedItem=['qty' => 0,'price'=>$spare->price,'item'=>$spare];
    if($this->spares){
        if(array_key_exists($id,$this->spares)){
            $storedItem=$this->spares[$id];
        }
    }
    $storedItem['qty']++;
    $storedItem['price']= $spare->price*$storedItem['qty'];
    $this->spares[$id]=$storedItem;
    $this->totalQuantity++;
    $this->totalPrice+=$spare->price;
}
```

}

my route

```
Route::get('/addToCart/{id}',['uses'=>'searchController@getAddToCart',
'as'=>'product.addToCart'] );
```

my controller

```
 public function getAddToCart(Request $request,$id){
     $spares=Spares::find($id);
     $oldCart=Session::has('cart')? Session::get('cart'):null;
     $cart=new Cart($oldCart);
     $cart->add($spares,$spares->id);

     $request->session()->put('cart',$cart);
     dd($request->session())->get('cart');
     return redirect()->back();

 }
```

This is the session image that i am currently getting i dont know whats this Store object. i cant access through the name 'cart'

[image]

The way that i should get is like following

[image]

This was the all session object inside dd method how to access only the cart part?
[image]

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `session()->push()` instead of `session()->put()`

```
$request->session()->push('cart', $cart);
```

As [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/session#storing-data) `put` will overwrite the pervious data and `push` will add new value to the session array.

Comment: I am using laravel 6.9 and I have the same problem. Above methods didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Slip this part

```
dd($request->session())->get('cart');
```

because it resets your cart session.
Use this function like this

```
public function AddCart(Request $request, $id)
{

    $product = Product::find($id);
    if($request->session()->exists('cart'))
    {
      $oldCart = $request->session()->get('cart');
    }
    else
    {
        $oldCart=false;
    }

    $Cart = new Cart($oldCart);
    $Cart->Add($product, $id);
    $request->session()->put('cart',$Cart);
    return redirect()->back();
```